# How to copy / clone content of a page in href mailto

Tags: wordpress, email, mailto

when a user clicks on the mailto: link the content of the page should be copied in his e-mail message-field.

Where I put the code for that in Wordpress.

I am not a coder. So please tell me the necessary steps to accomplish this.

Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us what you have tried so far. You are expected to do your research and make an attempt at the problem before posting here. Take a look at [how to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and update your question with the code you have tried in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and details of the exact problem so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

to create a mailto: link you need to add a line like this:

```
<a href="mailto:example@email.com?subject=Email%20Subject&body=Email%20Body%20Text">tu texto de anclaje</a>
```

If you want to edit the body of the mail, you can change the "body=**Email%20Body%20Text**".

If you're not a coder, you can use a plugin to insert the code.

Greetings.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advise. But I think I did not make my issue quite clear. I will try again. The mailto-link is already on a html-page. I.E. above this link is a text. e.g. "lorem ipusum dolorem". Somebody clicks now on the mailto link -> it opens his mailprogram and its message box is already filled in with the text of the page, i.e. "lorem ipsum dolorem". Btw. the text on the page differs always. So I need a code to get the text and " copies" it in the message body of the user's email program. Thanks